# want to write multiple doget method in same servlet class is it possible .....if so ...how.?

Tags: java, servlets

```
public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res) throws ServletException,IOException
    {
        String param1 = req.getParameter("x");
        String param2 = req.getParameter("y");
        String param3 = req.getParameter("z");
        int x = Integer.parseInt(param1);
        int y = Integer.parseInt(param2);
        int z = Integer.parseInt(param3);
```

Comment: like this i wanna write multiple methods

Comment: No, and what would it mean?  Why do you think you want to do this?

Comment: actually i have to get 3 values....three values have to be proccessed in different methods all the results are to be added to an array

Comment: So you're saying each variable, `x`, `y`, and `z`, should be handled by different methods if they exist? If so, I would simply have `doGet` delegate to the appropriate method based on which one of those variables exists.

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want more that one `doGet` in the same servlet, that kind of defeats the point. You would either have one `Servlet` that dispatches control to the appropriate controller (Prefered), or you would have one `Servlet` per request.

The `doGet` is an inherited method from `HttpServlet`, so you can overload the `doGet` method, but that those overloads can not be called. Since your implementation will be injected into the client, the client has coded using the `HttpServlet` class and your implementation is called polymorphically. As such, the client will only have access the the methods defined in `HttpServlet` and your overloaded implementations will not be known.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

**doGet(HttpServletRequest req,HttpServletResponse res)** is picked by the servlet container.So Yes You can have overloaded versions of doGet but they wont be recognized by Servlet Container.So it does not make sense to have multiple doGet.

Instead Overriding the doGet and doPost Methods in servlet makes sense.
[Refer this for more info.](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19857-01/819-6518/abxbe/index.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this if you want. But I do not recommend this. When you call GET, send another parameter, something like a function name, then use one get method, check the parameter sent before, define two functions and put the two logics that were put in your get.